# Do organizations ever use SharePoint on a port other than 80?

Tags: sharepoint

Has anyone encountered SharePoint installations that are set up to use other than port 80?  I'm not really concerned with test servers or administration interface usage.. just what users would be exposed to.

My application is currently set to leverage the WebDAV mini-redirector to assist with its SharePoint interface, and that software can't be used on SharePoint servers that use other than port 80.  Trying to figure out how big a problem I might have when this application is deployed widely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're not referring to the admin interface of SharePoint?

Even so, yes, people use different ports, even multiple IP addresses, host headers, etc. Your application should handle this, or it won't get very much use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we use port 443 ;)

Besides that I have the mysites set on a different port and that was primarily for a cheap/easy method to ensure that it not accessible through the firewall and also because SSL and host headers are a pain with IIS 6; and network services wanted to cut down on the number IP address allocated.

Most web applications I have run into have no problem using host headers or different port.  As for end user I think we are probably at the point were they are able to under ports and enter a different one when needed.